# How to define a New workflow in WSO2 API 1.7?

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

**WSO2 API 1.7** allows using workflows with the following standard event which are API Store centric and can be extended:

-> Application Creation

-> Application Registration

-> API Subscription

-> User SignUp

**I was interested in introducing a workflow when an API is promoted from CREATED to PUBLISHED state by an API Publisher.**

This would require defining a completely new workflow type, can someone please help me know if this can be achieved with WSO2 API 1.7 version?

Thanks,
Wajid

Answer (score 0):

you cannot add a workflow to the API publisher. You can modify or extend the workflows and plug them to the current existing workflows ( at 4 scenarios mentioned in your questions)